# Раccчитать высоту UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-development, uicollectionview

Есть `UICollectionView` с кастомными ячейками которые представлены в классе `FeedCell`

```
    class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    //Аватар автора
    let authorAvatar: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "author")
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return iv
    }()

    //Имя автора
    let authorNamedLabel: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "Иван Калягин"
        lb.font = lb.font.withSize(14)
        return lb
    }()

    let favoriteButtonStar: UIButton = {
        let bt = UIButton()
        bt.setImage(UIImage(named:"FeedStarOff"),for: .normal)
        return bt
    }()

    //Картинка статьи
    let thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "thumbnail")
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        //        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        return iv
    }()

    //Заголовок статьи
    let titlePostLabel: UILabel = {

        let tv = UILabel()
        tv.text = "6 причин, почему не нужно следовать общественному мнению"
        tv.text = tv.text?.uppercased()
        tv.numberOfLines = 0
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
        tv.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: 2.0)

        return tv
    }()

    let categoryPostLabel: UILabel = {
        let tv = UILabel()
        tv.text = "ОБРАЗ ЖИЗНИ"
        tv.text = tv.text?.uppercased()
        tv.numberOfLines = 0
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .semibold)
        tv.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.64, green: 0.64, blue: 0.64, alpha: 1.0)

        return tv
    }()
    let dataPostLabel: UILabel = {
        let tv = UILabel()
        tv.text = "16.01.2018"
        tv.numberOfLines = 0
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .regular)
        tv.textColor = UIColor.black
        tv.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.52, green: 0.52, blue: 0.52, alpha: 1.0)

        return tv
    }()

    let shortTextCut: UILabel = {
        let tv = UILabel()
        tv.text = "Сама наука восстала против этого, и теперь ты не будешь поддаваться мнению большинства, а будешь формировать собственные взгляды."
        tv.numberOfLines = 0
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)

        return tv
    }()

    let commentsToPost: UILabel = {
        let tv = UILabel()
        tv.text = "5 Комментариев"
        tv.numberOfLines = 0
        tv.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.52, green: 0.52, blue: 0.52, alpha: 1.0)
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .light)

        return tv
    }()

    let commentIcon: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "Comment")
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return iv
    }()

    func setupViews(){
        addSubview(authorAvatar)
        addSubview(authorNamedLabel)
        addSubview(favoriteButtonStar)
        addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
        addSubview(titlePostLabel)
        addSubview(categoryPostLabel)
        addSubview(dataPostLabel)
        addSubview(shortTextCut)
        addSubview(commentsToPost)
        addSubview(commentIcon)

        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|-15-[v0(30)]-10-[v1]-[v2]-15-|", views: authorAvatar,authorNamedLabel,favoriteButtonStar)
        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "V:|-15-[v0(30)]", views: authorAvatar)
        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "V:|-15-[v0(30)]", views: authorAvatar)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: authorNamedLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: authorAvatar, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 6))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: favoriteButtonStar, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: authorAvatar, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: thumbnailImageView)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: authorAvatar, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))

        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|-15-[v0]-15-|", views: titlePostLabel)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlePostLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 13))

        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|-15-[v0]-13-[v1]", views: categoryPostLabel, dataPostLabel)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: categoryPostLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: titlePostLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 9))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: dataPostLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: categoryPostLabel, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|-15-[v0]-15-|", views: shortTextCut)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: shortTextCut, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: categoryPostLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))

        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|-15-[v0(12)]-7-[v1]|", views: commentIcon,commentsToPost)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: commentIcon, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: shortTextCut, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 15))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: commentIcon, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: commentsToPost, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 3))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: commentIcon, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 12))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: commentIcon, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 12))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том, что высота ячейки постоянно меняется и необходимо сделать ее расчет автоматическим. Вот мой контроллер, в котором используется кастомные ячейки:

```
class FeedController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Свежее"

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    collectionView?.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 800)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте класс, наследуемый от UICollectionViewFlowLayout и в нем сможете полностью контролировать расположение элементов.